# servicestack ormlite sqlite DateTime getting TimeZone adjustment on insert

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

i'm trying ormlite.   i'm finding that when i insert an object with a DateTime property, it is getting -8:00 (my timezone is +8) applied by ormlite.  It should be inserted with literally what the time is.   in my case it is already UTC.

however reading the values out of ormlite, the +8 is not getting re-applied.

is this a known bug?

thanks

Comment: ormlite 3.9.32  sqlite 32bit

Answer (score 0):

I think it is inserted in UTC kind. After reading DateTime from database try to apply `.ToLocalTime()`

Answer (score 0):

So your question looks related to this pull request:
https://github.com/kojoru/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/d3f63ccd40f945b8dc03fd627ad49a895d4277de

If you check the code in `SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider.cs`, it looks like setting `SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider.EnsureUtc(true)` would fix your problem.

```
var dialect = new SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider();
dialect.EnsureUtc(true);
var factory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(cnnStr, dialect);
var connection = factory.Open();
```

Check `EnsureUtcTest.cs` for an example.  Old question, I know, but I hope that helps.