# Is there an OrmLite option for DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTimeKind.Utc)?

Tags: sql-server, utc, ormlite-servicestack

Is there a way to specify that I want **all** of the `DateTime`s that OrmLite materializes to be set to UTC kind?

I store a lot of `DateTime`s in my database via stored procedures when a row is inserted:

```
insert [Comment] (
  Body
, CreatedOn
) values (
  @Body
, getutcdate()
);
```

When I retrieve the values via a select statement in ormlite, the datetimes come out in `Unspecified` kind (which is interpreted as the local timezone, I believe):

```
var comments = db.SqlList<Comment>("select * from [Comment] where ... ");
```

I would prefer **not** to set each DateTime object individually:

```
foreach (var comment in comments) {
    comment.CreatedOn = DateTime.SpecifyKind(comment.CreatedOn, DateTimeKind.Utc);
}
```

I found this question, but I don't think it's quite what I'm asking for:
[servicestack ormlite sqlite DateTime getting TimeZone adjustment on insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250715/servicestack-ormlite-sqlite-datetime-getting-timezone-adjustment-on-insert/18580685#18580685)

Also found [this pull request](https://github.com/kojoru/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/d3f63ccd40f945b8dc03fd627ad49a895d4277de), but setting `SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider.EnsureUtc(true)` doesn't seem to do it either.

Comment: For those who may have landed on this page but are using OrmLite v3 with Sqlite dialect: there is a bug where if you persist a DateTime with a Kind of Utc, and a Milliseconds of 0, the Kind switches to Local when you read the DateTime back out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider.EnsureUtc(true)` **does work**, there was something else going on with my test case that led me to believe that it didn't.  Hopefully this will help someone else.

Here's some sample code:

**model.cs**

```
public class DateTimeTest {
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

**test.cs**

```
var connectionString = "server=dblcl;database=flak;trusted_connection=true;";
var provider = new SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider();
provider.EnsureUtc(true);
var factory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, provider);
var connection = factory.Open();

connection.CreateTable(true, typeof(DateTimeTest));
connection.ExecuteSql("insert DateTimeTest (CreatedOn) values (getutcdate())");
var results = connection.SqlList<DateTimeTest>("select * from DateTimeTest");

foreach(var result in results) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}", result.Id, result.CreatedOn, result.CreatedOn.Kind, result.CreatedOn.ToLocalTime(), result.CreatedOn.ToUniversalTime());
}
```

**output**

```
1,9/13/2013 5:19:12 PM,Utc,9/13/2013 10:19:12 AM,9/13/2013 5:19:12 PM
```